# Special character not displaying properly in Qt 5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unicode

My app uses "μ" symbol in a label, in Qt4 it displays fine but in Qt 5 it doesn't for the same code. I am using following two lines at two different places where it works fine in Qt4 :

```
QChar('μ').toLatin1()

QString::fromUtf8(rateText.toLatin1()));
```

In second case the string contains the "μ" symbol.

In my main main.cpp, I have added following code:

```
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
#else
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
#endif
```

**Edit:**

This line is enough in Qt 5 as Qt 5 uses utf-8 as default

```
 ui->timeLabel->setText("Time = "+rateText);  //rateText contains 'μ' symbol
```

But it doesn't work in Qt4, even this does not work

```
ui->timeLabel->setText("Time = "+rateText.toUtf8());
```

Only this worked for me:

```
ui->timeLabel->setText("Time = "+QString::fromUtf8(rateText.toLatin1()));
```

And  I need a single solution which works across

Comment: This may be issue with source code encoding. Are you sure your `'μ'` in the source file is in the same encoding your compiler uses for source?

Answer (score 3):

```
 QString::fromUtf8(rateText.toLatin1()));
```

This doesn't make sense: you convert a string to latin1, just to the interpret the latin1 string as UTF8. You shouldn't do such conversions at all unless you explicitly need a QByteArray/const char*.
`toLatin1()` will convert the micro sign to `0xb5`, while the micro sign in UTF-8 would be `0xc2b5`.

So instead of

```
 QString foo = QString::fromUtf8(rateText.toLatin1()));
```

just do

```
 QString foo = rateText;
```

If you need to convert to byte array, make sure you convert back from the same encoding you converted to.

```
QByteArray ba = rateText.toUtf8();
... do stuff with ba
QString s = QString::fromUtf8(ba);
```

There should be only few occasions where this is needed though.

To track down encoding errors, I suggest to disable any implicit const char*/QByteArray <-> QString conversions via

```
DEFINES += QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII
```

Comment: Try: `tr("Time: %1").arg(rateText)` or `QString::fromLatin1("Time: %1").arg(rateText)`. If the QString contains the correct character, conversion can only break it, not fix it. setText() takes a QString, rateText is a QString, there's nothing to convert. implicit conversion is only applied to the "Time: " literal, but that's not critical here as it doesn't contain any non-ascii character.

Comment: I'd assume the `μ` isn't correct in rateText in the first place and your conversions work around that. Try `QChar(0xB5)` and don't convert to it latin1 along the way.